# How do I get the first and last initial/character from a name string

Tags: java, android, regex

I am trying to extract the first character of both first and last name from a string but have had no luck so far.( tried searching multiple solutiosn online, no luck either)
So for example, if this is the string:

```
name = A A BCD EFG
```

I want to display just A and E ( say AE).
I am trying to figure out if theres an easier way to do this. The regex I am using, does get me the first character, but doesnt work for the last character, it returns (AEFG) ,aka the whole of last name instead.
Is there a way to go about this? Here's my code:

```
 String lastName = "";
        String firstName= "";

        if(name.split("\\w+").length>1){

            lastName = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf(" ")+1,1);
            firstName = name.substring(0,1);
        }
        else{
            firstName = name;
        }
        String completeInitials = firstName + " " + lastName;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this regex to capture the first letter of first name in group1 and first letter of lastname in group2 and replace whole match with `$1$2` to get the desired string.

```
^\s*([a-zA-Z]).*\s+([a-zA-Z])\S+$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Start of string
- `\s*` - Matches optional whitespace(s)
- `([a-zA-Z])` - Matches the first letter of firstname and captures it in group1
- `.*\s+` - Here `.*` matches any text greedily and `\s+` ensures it matches the last whitespace just before last name
- `([a-zA-Z])` - This captures the first letter of lastname and captures it in group2
- `\S+$` - Matches remaining part of lastname and end of input

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/c3AWbI/1)**

Java code,

```
String s = "A A BCD EFG";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("^\\s*([a-zA-Z]).*\\s+([a-zA-Z])\\S+$", "$1$2"));
```

Prints,

```
AE
```

**Edit:** To convert/ensure the replaced text to upper case, in case the name is in lower case letters, in PCRE based regex you can use `\U` just before the replacement as `\U$1$2` but as this post is in Java, it won't work that way and hence you can use `.toUpperCase()`

**[Demo for ensuring the replaced text is in upper case](https://regex101.com/r/c3AWbI/2)**

Java code for same would be to use `.toUpperCase()`

```
String s = "a A BCD eFG";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("^\\s*([a-zA-Z]).*\\s+([a-zA-Z])\\S+$", "$1$2").toUpperCase());
```

Prints in upper case despite the input string in lower case,

```
AE
```

Comment: @MarissaNicholas: Yea, right, it doesn't allow before first 15 minutes. Thanks for accepting. Let me know if you further face any issues or have any queries anytime :)

Comment: just as an update, do you know how i can make these initials capital letters?

Comment: In PCRE based regex, you can use `\U` just before the replacement part `\U$1$2` to turn them to upper case but in Java I don't think that works. But in Java you can invoke `.toUpperCase()` to turn all the string to upper case. Let me update this in my answer.

Comment: actually i forgot about to uppercase! thanks for your answer!

Comment: Hey, do you happen to have any idea about my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57598276/how-do-i-pass-a-multi-part-body-parameter-for-rxjava2-androidnetworking-post-req ( about uploading an image to server)

Comment: @AngelaHeely: Hey sorry I couldn't reply to your message as I had been quite occupied into some other works but I see someone already posted a great working answer for you so its all good. I was indeed wondering how did you reach to me through this answer, which seems to be couple of months old. I will try to get back to Stackoverflow so that I can be of help to you and others. Indeed I miss being here and helping others but past couple of months had been terribly busy in some other stuff.

Comment: no worries! I actually tried commenting on random android threads while searching and commented on people who answered. That's how I commented here aswell. Any help will be greatly appreciated! thanks for responding!

Answer (score 3):

What about this: split the name `String` into parts. Then take the first `char` of the first and the last part.

This solution prints both initials (first name and last name) in case both are present and just one initial (name) if only a first name or a last name is given.

```
private void printInitials(String name) {
    String[] nameParts = name.split(" ");
    String firstName = nameParts[0];
    char firstNameChar = firstName.charAt(0);
    if (nameParts.length > 1) {
        System.out.println("First character of first name: " + firstNameChar);
        String lastName = nameParts[nameParts.length - 1];
        char lastNameChar = lastName.charAt(0);
        System.out.println("First character of last name: " + lastNameChar);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("First character name: " + firstNameChar);
    }
}
```

So, in case of `A A BCD EFG`, it prints:

```
First character of first name: A
First character of last name: E
```

And in case of 'AABCDEFG`, it prints:

```
First character name: A
```

Answer (score 0):

With Kotlin;

```
"Sample Name".replace("^\\s*([a-zA-Z]).*\\s+([a-zA-Z])\\S+$".toRegex(), "$1$2")?.uppercase()
```

or use this extension. for "Sample" -> "SA", "S" -> "S"

```
fun String?.toTwoChar(): String {

    return when {
        isNullOrEmpty() -> {
            "?"
        }
        contains(" ") -> {
            replace("^\\s*([a-zA-Z]).*\\s+([a-zA-Z])\\S+$".toRegex(), "$1$2").uppercase()
        }
        length > 1 -> {
            substring(0, 2)
        }
        else -> {
            substring(0, 1)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split all words by ' '. For each word return the first character, and join it again

```
   string.split(' ').map((element,index,array)=>{
    if(index == 0 || index==array.length-1 ){   
        return element[0]
    }
    }).join('')
```

`